# Как исправить кодировку при чтении .properties файла?

Tags: java, spring, utf-8, кодировка, io

Есть класс который подтягиват данные из файла `css-selector.properties`, но кириллические символы лоомаются превращаясь в иероглифы. Как это исправить?

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class SelectorsStore implements Store<String, String> {

    @NotNull
    private Map<String, String> selectors = Maps.newHashMap();

    @Override
    public String get(@NotNull String key) {
        return selectors.get(key);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void fetchProp() {
        String path = format("%s/css-selector.properties", new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        try (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(path)) {
            properties.load(in);
            properties.stringPropertyNames().forEach(name -> selectors.put(name, properties.getProperty(name)));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("File css-selector.properties not found", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Если у `Spring` есть способ сделать это короче, на подобии `@Value`, только вытянуть сразу всю `Map<String, String>` разом, то буду признателен за подсказку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Property-файлы могут содержать только символы латиницы. Поэтому любые другие символы должны быть преобразованы в формат [Unicode Escape Sequences](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5137). Для этого файл с кириллицей надо перед использованием обработать с помощью утилиты [native2ascii](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/native2ascii.html).

Answer (score 2):

Если вам нужна кириллица в properties файлах, рекомендую вам рассмотреть вопрос о переходе на XML формат, см. [java.util.Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html). Обычные properties файлы, как уже ответили выше, кириллицу содержать не должны... не по ГОСТУ :)

Answer (score 2):

Properties файлы хранятся в кодировке ISO_8859_1.

Соответственно,

```
@Value("${app.mail.email.subject}")
private String parEmailSubject; //придет в StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1
```

а при нужде учитываем, что parEmailSubject принят из proprerties file, а тот в такой кодировке.

```
    String emailSubject =new String(parEmailSubject.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));
```